# Fetching SQL rows by conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i trying to fetch some rows by some conditions , but its not working as i want;
please take look on my code and share your ideas.

```
            $query = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE 
                `name`      =       '$nameFA'   OR 
                `name`      =       '$nameLA'   OR
                `ft`        LIKE    '%$nameFA%' OR
                `ft`        LIKE    '%$nameLA%' AND
                `information`   LIKE    '%$info%'
            ");
```

as you see, the input of `name` and `ft` may have two different values.
and rows should be fetch if `information` have something like `$info` variable.

Comment: you're mixing `or`  and `and` conditions without `()` to delimit them. Unless you're very familiar with mysql's operator precedence rules, I suggest you put in explicit `()` to nail down what your logic should be. e.g. `(X or Y or Z) AND (P)`

Comment: The code is ALWAYS working. Sometimes it doesn't do what we wanted it to do. Maybe if you supply the table and the desired output?

Comment: @MarcB , thnx for quick responde , i never used `or` and `and` without `( )` , is it going to be a problem ? i wrote A LOTS of queries like above. i cant figure out what youre saying , can you please rewrite the query in the way you say ?

Comment: I have no idea what your logic is supposed to be, so all I'd be doing is littering brackets in a way that still won't make the query work properly.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos ! you're absolutely , i agree, the code works, but not the way i want. have you any idea how can i get my things to work ?

Comment: @MarcB so what you're saying is i do that like this : ` ( name=$nameFA OR name=$nameLA ) AND ... ` do i get it correct ?

Comment: Try specifying what the input is, what do you expect it to do, what it is actually doing

Comment: @AlexandreSantos , thnx alot , i will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way :

```
$query = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE 
    (`name`      =       '$nameFA'   OR 
    `name`      =       '$nameLA'   OR
    `ft`        LIKE    '%$nameFA%' OR
    `ft`        LIKE    '%$nameLA%')
    AND `information`   LIKE    '%$info%'
");
```

Or this way, since i we don't know what you want to do we can't know how to place parenthesis:

```
$query = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE 
    `name`      =       '$nameFA'   OR 
    `name`      =       '$nameLA'   OR
    `ft`        LIKE    '%$nameFA%' OR
    (`ft`        LIKE    '%$nameLA%' AND
        `information`   LIKE    '%$info%'
    )
");
```

**ALWAYS** add parenthesis when you have multiple AND OR AND OR in a statement.

consider :

- a = being a dog
- b = barking
- c = walking

a OR b AND C is true when : (you are a dog, OR your are barking) AND you are walking

a OR (b AND C) is true when : you are a dog, OR (barking AND walking)